Where are d:DataType and d:DesignInstance documented?
I'm using d:DataContext like this:
<Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:NodeItemViewModel}">

My intention is to gain Intellisense support within the xaml editor. I do not need an actual instance (e.g. for Blend) - and am assuming IsDesignTimeCreatable=False is the default. Also, I'm assuming that the above is a shorthand for {d:DesignInstance Type=...}.
Are my assumptions correct and where can I find proper documentation for this feature? I've been working with xaml for a few years now and I just now stumbled across this feature after actively searching the web for something that has the same benefits (during editing only) as "DataTemplate DataType" does. I'm suprised, this is not part of the default markup that Visual Studio provides when creating a new control, like {d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type system:Object}} - if just to nudge developers towards specifying the intended data type.
The best - but not really sufficient - docs I found were:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ee823176(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#setting-the-design-time-data-context (from 2012)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2022#design-time-data-basics (from 2022)
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/879109/Using-Design-time-Databinding-While-Developing-a-W

Hi,@mike. I found a sample document about d:DesignInstance. You could refer to here.
